# How to convert picture to visio object?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I edit a word doc which contains pictures which I know were visio objects and were copied and pasted as images by mistake. Is there a way to convert them back to be visio objects?

Answer (score 0):

No. They can be used as images within Visio but they will still be just images.